# Redis Real Time counter value to android

Tags: android, mysql, redis

I am developing an application which need to display real time counter value stored in redis.Moreover I am trying to send a updated value to each device when application is opened.One traditional method I know is to pull value after some interval but that not seems to be a good solution.can anyone please suggest me what seems to be a good solution for this?

Comment: when user open app and login through webservice you get value each time with user credential.

Comment: @DrewPierce As I am using amazon web services,pulling can increase my bandwidth usage which can cost me out.:(

Comment: either decide an interval you can live with or do socket programming

Comment: @DrewPierce I am developing the photo sharing application and counters are nothing but photo likes.Users can se real time likes for a particular photo moreover photos gonna be in millions i dont think your suggested trick is going to work here.